# mongodb not starting after upgrade to 5.0.4

Tags: mongodb

I have upgraded my mongodb to 5.0 , but after upgrade mongodb startup got failed . below is the error ,

● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Wed 2021-12-01 13:54:17 EST; 23s ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 245014 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
Main PID: 245014 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

Dec 01 13:54:16 JAXDBA1 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 01 13:54:17 JAXDBA1 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Dec 01 13:54:17 JAXDBA1 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.

Comment: Hi Joachim,

below is the os spec am using ,

Comment: cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

Comment: script used for upgrade

Comment: Update the list file for apt/MongoDB
To remove the old list run “sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list”

Now add the new one with 
sudo echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

Run “sudo apt-get update” to update apt’s lists.

Step 4: Upgrade the MongoDB install
sudo apt-get upgrade -y

Comment: according to the official procedure you need to upgrade to latest mongod 4.4 with fcv 4.4 before upgrading the binary to 5.0 ...

Comment: its already set to 4.4

Comment: test01_rs:SECONDARY> db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )
{
        "featureCompatibilityVersion" : {
                "version" : "4.4"
        },
        "ok" : 1,

Comment: can see this message from syslog,

Dec  1 15:37:57 JAXMONGODBA1 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Dec  1 15:37:57 JAXMONGODBA1 kernel: [15338461.806656] traps: mongod[35723] trap invalid opcode ip:5602a14ef2fa sp:7ffc54850590 error:0 in mongod[56029d52d000+50f9000]
Dec  1 15:37:58 JAXMONGODBA1 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Dec  1 15:37:58 JAXMONGODBA1 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.

please check on this

Comment: Did you check the mongod logfile?

Comment: there is no any log generated, didnt found any log after the upgrade

Comment: Check your config file `/etc/mongod.conf`, for `systemLog.path` entry. This logfile should provide more information. And please don't put the content as comment, edit your question and add it there.

Comment: hi Wernfried,

path mentioned in config file is /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log , but there is no log in the location, its clean .

thanks